# flex boostrap 4 grid overlapping row height and using collapse class

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, row, col

[image]

Let's say I have this kind of grid columns bootstrap 4 (image on the left) and then I collapse the card 1 using boostrap collapse, and I expected the grid 3 to overlapping the height of row (and the result will be on the right image)

I have tried it using align-item-start and align-self-start, turns out it just like the row class bootstrap..

my investigation is that grid 1 and 2 covered by row class that has certain height (if height 1 < 2 then height 2 will be the row height and vice versa..

is this even possible using bootstrap 4?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row no-gutter">
  <div class="col-7">
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
      <!-- Card Header - Dropdown -->
      <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Data Rekam Medis</h6>
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary mb-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseRekamMedis" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseRekamMedis">
                        Toggle
                    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse show" id="collapseRekamMedis">
        <!-- Card Body -->
        <div class="card-body py-2">
          <div class="row mb-2">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-right">
                                <nobr>Pasien<i class="text text-danger">*</i></nobr>
                            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control number text-right" name="anamnesa" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mb-2">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-right">Berat Badan<i class="text text-danger">*</i></label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control number text-right" name="anamnesa" />
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <span class="input-group-text">kg</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mb-2">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-right">
                                <nobr>Tekanan Darah<i class="text text-danger">*</i></nobr>
                            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control number text-center" name="sistole" />
                <div class="input-group-append input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text">/</span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control number text-center" name="diastole" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-2 row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-right">Perabaan<i class="text text-danger">*</i></label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="perabaan" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-2 row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-right">Pengamatan<i class="text text-danger">*</i></label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pengamatan" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-2 row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-right">Penciuman<i class="text text-danger">*</i></label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="penciuman" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-2 row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-right">Diagnosa<i class="text text-danger">*</i></label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="diagnosa" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mb-2">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-right">Sindrom<i class="text text-danger">*</i></label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sindrom" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-right">Anamnesa<i class="text text-danger">*</i></label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <textarea class="form-control" name="sindrom" rows="4"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-right">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn_save"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> &nbsp;Simpan</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5 float-right">
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
      <!-- Card Header - Dropdown -->
      <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Informasi Pasien</h6>
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary mb-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsePatientData" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsePatientData">
                        Toggle
                    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse show" id="collapsePatientData">
        <!-- Card Body -->
        <div class="card-body py-2">
          <div class="mb-0 row">
            <label class="col-4 col-form-label text-right">
                                <nobr>Pasien <i class="text text-danger">*</i></nobr>
                            </label>
            <div class="col-8">
              <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="patient_name" value="Maman Abdurrahman">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-0 row">
            <label class="col-4 col-form-label text-right">Usia</label>
            <div class="col-8">
              <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="patient_name" value="25 thn">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-0 row">
            <label class="col-4 col-form-label text-right">Diagnosa</label>
            <div class="col-8">
              <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="patient_name" value="Radang tenggorokan">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-0 row">
            <label class="col-4 col-form-label text-right">Anamnesa</label>
            <div class="col-12">
              <textarea class="form-control-plaintext" id="patient_name" rows="6">publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available</textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-7">
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
      <!-- Card Header - Dropdown -->
      <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Data Rekam Medis</h6>
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary mb-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsesRekamMedis" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsesRekamMedis">
                        Toggle
                    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse show" id="collapsesRekamMedis">
        <!-- Card Body -->
        <div class="card-body py-2">
          <div class="row mb-2">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-right">
                                <nobr>Pasien<i class="text text-danger">*</i></nobr>
                            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control number text-right" name="anamnesa" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mb-2">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-right">Berat Badan<i class="text text-danger">*</i></label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control number text-right" name="anamnesa" />
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <span class="input-group-text">kg</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mb-2">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-right">
                                <nobr>Tekanan Darah<i class="text text-danger">*</i></nobr>
                            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control number text-center" name="sistole" />
                <div class="input-group-append input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text">/</span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control number text-center" name="diastole" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-2 row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-right">Perabaan<i class="text text-danger">*</i></label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="perabaan" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-2 row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-right">Pengamatan<i class="text text-danger">*</i></label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pengamatan" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-2 row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-right">Penciuman<i class="text text-danger">*</i></label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="penciuman" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-2 row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-right">Diagnosa<i class="text text-danger">*</i></label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="diagnosa" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mb-2">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-right">Sindrom<i class="text text-danger">*</i></label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sindrom" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-right">Anamnesa<i class="text text-danger">*</i></label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <textarea class="form-control" name="sindrom" rows="4"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-right">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn_save"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> &nbsp;Simpan</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, turns out you don't need to user `.row` class..

simply using `.float-left` and `.float-right` on each div

FINAL CODE

```
<div class="col-7 float-left"></div>
<div class="col-4 float-right"></div>
<div class="col-7 float-left"></div>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Columns are already aligned with either floats or flexbox.